# In an equilibrium of two systems, why is not true that $\frac{\delta S_{1}}{\delta N_{1}} = \frac{\delta S_{2}}{\delta N_{2}}$?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, equilibrium

Why is not true that $\frac{\delta S_{1}}{\delta N_{1}} = \frac{\delta S_{2}}{\delta N_{2}}$ across two systems that exchange particles?

It is true, instead, that $\frac{\delta F_{1}}{\delta N_{1}} = \frac{\delta F_{2}}{\delta N_{2}}$.

My thoughts: $F$ also takes into account the energy gained or lost by interacting components of some system. As a result, minimizing $F$ (remember that $-\Delta F = W_{by}$) also forces system components to do work and reduce in energy.

Comment: Aren't these two statements equivalent? $\frac{\partial S_1}{\partial N_1} = - \frac{\partial^2 F_1}{\partial T_1  \partial N_1}$ but $T_1 = T_2$ at equilibrium and you recover the same statement about F?

Comment: well as you stated yourself: the difference between entropy and frenergy is the internal energy. Or differently: You can only make the usual stability arguments in the "natural variables" which for the entropy are E,V,N but since you fix the temperature (F=F(T,V,N=N_1+N_2)) well.. you know nothing, Jon Snow

Comment: @JohnM If you take the derivative first with respect to N and then with respect to T, the internal energy term $U$ in $F = U - TS$ can be shown to drop out in a system with the same type of particles (and, thus, which have the same value for $U = N\Delta$. However, am I right that $\delta S_{1} / \delta N_{1}$ is meaningless when we have different particle types?

Comment: @Muno It is not meaningless, but then you have two chemical potentials, both of which have to be equal in both systems, if they are connected (such that there is particle exchange).

Comment: @SebastianRiese But $\frac{\delta F_{1}}{\delta N_{1}}$ = $\frac{\delta F_{2}}{\delta N_{2}}$ doesn't have to require = that $\frac{\delta S_{1}}{\delta N_{1}}$ = $\frac{\delta S_{2}}{\delta N_{2}}$. So isn't the relationship between S and N non-essential?

Comment: @Muno In any case you always have to specify which quantities are constant when you take the partial derivative. It is easily for people to misunderstand or to confuse yourself if you do not do so in thermodynamics. [On the other hand it is often acceptable in mechanics, field theories]